# Will NPCs poisoned weapons run out of poison?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If you you give poisoned bows to an NPC, do the poisoned arrows ever run out?

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, this question's asking if an already poisoned weapon will wear out if a companion uses it rather than if a companion will use poisons from the inventory

Comment: Thanks yeah, since they never run out of arrows, I was wondering if I found poison for the weapon, if it would always be poisoned for the npc that was using it... but now I know it works the same as if the main character had it.

Comment: The first part was pretty much a duplicate, so I removed it and left the portion about the poison not running out. Feel free to reword if you can improve it. I can't retract my close vote that I can see.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can give poisoned bows (or any other weapon) to your followers.  They will use them to attack, but the poison wears off after 1 hit just like your own weapons.

Comment: Ah.. I see I noticed that whatever arrows you give them they use infinitely, was wondering if they use poisoned infinitely Thanks I understand now

Comment: @wesley the bow gets poisoned, not the arrow.